# Efficiently/elegantly apply a method to, or get property from, numpy ndarray of objects

Tags: python, numpy

In a `python` script, have 2 `numpy` ndarrays filled with objects, let's call them `inA` and `inB` (same `shape`). The objects are all of the same type and have a method `calculate()` and a property `size`.

**I'd like to apply the method to each, and save the result in a new array, and I'd also like to get the property from each element and save the result in a new array.**

*Note: I have found ways to achieve all of this, but I think they could be improved. I just don't know how.*

#### Getting property or applying method without arguments

If the method takes no arguments, or non-array arguments, I have found a way to apply it to each element, like so:

```
f = lambda x: x.calculate()
outA = np.vectorize(f)(inA)
```

The same goes for getting the property:

```
f = lambda x: x.size
outA = np.vectorize(f)(inA)
```

This is working, but it's ugly (imho), and the fact that `x` in the lambda function is unknown to the IDE makes me having to write the function 'blindly', without help from intellisense (or it's Spyder equivalent).

#### Pairwise application of method

If the method takes another object as its argument, and I'd like to apply it to each element in `inA` and use the corresponding element in `inB` as its argument, the only thing I can come up with is a dreaded loop:

```
out = np.ndarray(inA.shape)
for index, iA in np.ndenumerate(inA):
    out[index] = iA.calculate(inB[index])
```

I refuse to believe there is no better way to achieve this.

Hence my question: **is there a way to improve on these two methods** (no pun intended) **of applying a method to elements or pairs of elements in an ndarray?**

Comment: Just don't use a `numpy` array of objects, use a vanilla Python `list`, that would be the better way.

Comment: I've used `np.frompyfunc` in the same way to create and access object elements.  `np.vectorize` uses it, but with more overhead.  It returns an array of objects.  Object dtype arrays contain pointers to the objects, much like lists.  Most of the fast compile numpy methods don't apply.

Comment: `np.frompyfunc(lambda x,y: x.calculate(y), 2,1)(inA, inB)` might work for the pairwise.  You can even get a cartesian application if `inA` and `inB` broadcast appropriately (one is (n,1) the other (m,) shaped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applying a method, I found I can do

```
outA = np.vectorize(className.calculate)(inA)
```

and for the paiwise application of a method, I found that I can do

```
out = np.vectorize(className.calculate)(inA, inB)
```

as the first argument of the methods is `self`.

Especially for the latter, this is *a lot* cleaner.

I haven't found a way to ge the property without a `lambda` function, I guess this

```
outA = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.size)(inA)
```

is the easiest/best way to do it in a oneliner.